# Execute just part of a method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a method that could potentially do both parts of the greater task at hand. Basically I have two buttons one button uses the entire method and returns a result at the bottom of the method. Now, my question is about the second button. The second button needs to do everything in that same method but only from line x of said method. Instead of writing a second method that repeats the same exact code from line x down of said method is there a way to jump over bits of code and only execute portions of a method in javascript? Or perhaps I am thinking about this all wrong?

Comment: Working with line numbers (if it was even possible) wouldn't be maintainable at all. What happens if you add or remove code? Writing two functions is the best and really the only way to go about this.

Comment: Break up the function into smaller components and spread to multiple functions, or use control flow, (if...) to manage the execution.

Answer (score 4):

Do two separate methods like this:

```
function a(){
//do first half of function
b();
}

function b(){
//do second half of function
}
```

Comment: and if you still want to run both at once: `function c(){ a(); b(); };`

Comment: Why didn't I think of this!?

Answer (score 1):

2 ways,

- split out the chunk that gets used twice into a separate method, and call from either within the first method, or from the other context directly.
- add another argument to the method that expects a boolean value. The function then skips over the unneeded bits based on that value passed in. It can then be called differently from different contexts.

Comment: 3 ways :) and one actually is exactly this one which was mentioned by author of question

Answer (score 0):

you can call String(yourfunc) to get code, then dynamically create second function  by cutting only further lines, you can get array of lines by splitting by ('\n') then join array elements from place you want to begin and evaluate new function, code:

```
    function split(bigfunc,line){
      for(var small = String(bigfunc).split('\n'), i=line,n='',l=small.length;++i<l;)
        n+=small[i];
      return eval('(function(args){'+n+')'};
    }
```

where args in last line you need to replace with args from original function, eventually you can assume args will be the same, then replace line with:
`return eval('('+small[0]+n+')')` if you're putting { after arguments of function like me or put +'{'+ between small[0] and n if you're putting { in new line.

it'll return new function with only code after line.
Dude, look how many lines of code will you save...

To be serious - it's overkill. I'm using dynamic code manipulation like this to dynamically create webworkers only with parts of code from primary thread and crafting blobs and urls to them in fly to reduce loading time. But it's way more serious purpose than just making code shorter, but...

at least it'll be soooo pro xD

Comment: btw - executing 2 functions is slower than one, so that this method achieves best performannce/lines of code ratio, as... it creates new n lines function in... 3 lines if you'll put } in the same line as rerurn, but like i said - it counts with REALLY high performance code as its some kind of precomputing code